# Add the label down from the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using `ggplot2` it gives the box of legends for every line in the right of the plot

Is there any command which could add this box under the plot like this one:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`legend.position = "bottom"` is what you are looking for:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, col = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(col = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to remove the name of the columns (example the factor(cyl))?

Comment: @ErikBodg it is! :) Please see the update (hint: look at `labs(col = NULL)`)